# Bootstrap Logo Link not working when Navbar is Collapsed?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I realized that my CSS `position:absolute;`in the `.navbar-header` code is what made my brand link unclickable. I changed it to `position:relative;`, but it made the Navbar disproportioned. I would imagine this has happened to a lot of people out there. So I'm wondering if anyone out there knows how to fix this, or am I stuck rebuilding from the ground up?

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="IMG" class="navbar-brand">
        <img alt="Brand" <img src="https://i.imgur.com/a509iUv.png"
             class="img" alt="Logo" width="30" height="25">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-button">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">   
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class=""><a></a></li>
      <li class=""><a></a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class=""><a></a></li>
      <li class=""><a></a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class=""><a></a></li>
      <li class=""><a></a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-header{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

Comment: Try fixing your HTML first. Your <img> tag is invalid.

Comment: Refer to the Docs > [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)